# Facebook Registration linking to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, facebook

I'm relatively new to website programming and any tips or help is much appreciated.

I have designed a golf site for my region in the UK, and I would like to implement [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) Login/Registration [facebook-connect](/questions/tagged/facebook-connect) for easy access and sign-ups. I have gone over the facebook developers website a few times but goes over my head a little.

I have the login button fine, but for registration I would like to access the users information in a [tag:MySQL} database. Does anyone know how to do this? I have set parameters in the database which are:

- id
- fb_id
- name
- email
- gender
- birthday
- location

However, it says: -

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'near) NOT NULL, `birthday` DATE NOT NULL, `location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQ' at line 1
```

How can I rectify the problem and then successfully have my registration login redirect to MySQL?

Essentially I would like a separate profile for each user who can share golf stats, organise games with friends and post recent scores.

Let me know your thoughts and any tips are welcomed.

Thanks,
Darren

Comment: give us the SQL. it has the error, not your columns.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access Facebook data with MySQL, which is not possible. Try using the native Facebook connect APIs instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So basically I have to use the Facebook code provided on their developer website? Would be great if you have example code of your own.